# How to get Spark ApplicationID using Main Class and user

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using Hadoop 2.0 with Cloudera and trying a Java program that will check if a particular Spark applicationID is running or not and take further steps.

I have Main Class and user (account) information which triggered a particular Spark Application.

I am aware of below but is there any Java API that can help parse and match using Main class name and user name ?

```
yarn application -list
```

Is there any way we can get the applicationID of a running spark Application by using Main Class and user information in another Java program ?

[EDIT] One way to is to issue below command :

```
yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING | grep $application_name | grep $user | cut -f 1
```

If there is any Java API that can simplify, please share.

[EDIT] Above command is fine however I tried with YarnClient as below:

public class SomeCheck {

```
    public boolean run(String account, String appName) throws YarnException, IOException {




        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn").setAppName("SomeCheck"));
        YarnConfiguration conf = new YarnConfiguration(SparkHadoopUtil.get().newConfiguration(sc.getConf()));

        YarnClient yarnClient = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
        yarnClient.init(conf);
        yarnClient.start();
        EnumSet<YarnApplicationState> states =
                  EnumSet.of(YarnApplicationState.ACCEPTED, YarnApplicationState.RUNNING);

        List<ApplicationReport> applications = yarnClient.getApplications(states);


        for (ApplicationReport application : applications) {
               if ((application.getUser() == account) & (application.getName() == appName)) return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

It is failing with pointing to `SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn").setAppName("SomeCheck"));`

Error:

```
 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'
```

Is there anything incorrect in the code ?

Comment: Do you know just the main-class or also the spark application name (this has to be set it you init the spark context )

Comment: Yes. I can get spark application name as well.

Comment: I am a little confused, is it the same application monitoring itself or a second application monitoring the Spark job?

Comment: Second application monitoring the spark job.

Comment: hi did you find it useful ? I gave complete example. if you care please accept answer as owner and vote up

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram I went with Unix method however will try this as well and accept/vote. Thank you for the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the application id in current spark application code itself.

here is the sample (Scala) code snippet java also has same api.

```
// create spark configuration
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local");
conf.set("spark.app.name", "test");

// create a spark context
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);

// get the application id
String appId = sc.applicationId();

// print the application id
System.out.println("Application id:  " + appId);

// stop the spark context
sc.stop();
```

Please try this.

Comment: This has to be from a different program that has to check if a particular application is running or not and it will only have that corresponding application main class name, user, and application name (if required).

Comment: I have got a unix command that works for me (edited the question). However checking if there is any java api to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The above approach suggested by Vijay will work for currently running application.

But seems like your requirement is to get all the applications.

---

> Question : is there any Java API that can help parse and match using
>   Main class name and user name ?

See the hadoop docs [YarnClient  ...here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html)

Basically, `YarnClient` has `getApplications` which will get all the apps.

> abstract
>   List   getApplications(EnumSet
>   applicationStates) Get a report (ApplicationReport) of Applications
>   matching the given application states in the cluster.

You can try something like this which will print all the applications periodically

```
import org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.YarnClient
public class YarnMonitor {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn").setAppName("Yarn Monitor"));

        YarnClient yarnClient = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
        YarnConfiguration yarnConf = new YarnConfiguration(SparkHadoopUtil.get().newConfiguration(sc.getConf()));

        while(true){ // periodically loop and get currently running apps

            yarnClient = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
            List<ApplicationReport> applications = yarnClient.getApplications();

            for (ApplicationReport application : applications) {
                System.out.println(application.getName());
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep for 1000 ms
        }
    }
```